# Application super wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

Does anybody know how these guys made such an application?
http://www.facebook.com/Disney?sk=app_168179776575247

The above part is quite clear for me, but the Top News part, I don't get how they technically achieved that. 
As far as I know, the Graph API doesn't let you access the content of a page wall. And even if this were possible, how can they display the Facebook videos the same way as Facebook does?
Did they entirely rewrote the Facebook wall?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something you need i am working on something very similar that works with all Facebook pages and applications.  This is for a social plugin i am developing and is going to be free to use for anyone.

http://apps.facebook.com/anotherfeed/TimeLineFeed.php?pageid=disney

Currently it only displays feed or posts from a single wall but looping through multiple walls would not be so difficult with a good time based algorithm.

I am using PHP-SDK 3.1.1 for auth and graph api access.
SEE: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php for php sdk
and 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for feed and post

Comment: Styling is not an issue, i just chose to render this similar to Facebook's new Timeline Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a clone of Facebook's wall yep. It is effectively a news feed with custom made articles meant to look like status updates that click through to the user, has graph api 'like' counts etc

Not much else I can say but with a bit of time these things are easily replicated :)